# Can't retrieve Display Name, username, and all other properties using Microsoft.Graph

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, blazor-server-side

I have a Blazor application (probably, that could be any web application) that uses Microsoft.Graph to retrieve user data from AD B2C. But all the properties of the retrieved user are null. I have User.Read.All permission granted. Here is my code:

```
        IConfidentialClientApplication confidentialClientApplication = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder
            .Create(_adB2CSettings.ClientId)
            .WithTenantId(_adB2CSettings.TenantId)
            .WithClientSecret(_adB2CSettings.ClientSecret)
            .Build();

        ClientCredentialProvider authenticationProvider = new ClientCredentialProvider(confidentialClientApplication);

        GraphServiceClient graphServiceClient = new GraphServiceClient(authenticationProvider);

        return await graphServiceClient.Users[userId].Request().GetAsync();
```

I even tried

```
return await graphServiceClient.Users[userId].Request().Select("displayName,mail,country,contacts,contactFolders").GetAsync();
```

But id did not help. What am I missing?

Comment: The code looks good. Does it even get any value for the property id or userPrincipalName in the user object?

Comment: @VivekN It has only ODataType (value "microsoft.graph.user") and AdditionalData, which has json with all the users data. But I would not be able to tell which one of them is the one I am interested in.

Comment: Make sure to use beta endpoint, and use the graph explorer website to get the right attribute names, some of the ones you used will definitely be null.

Comment: @Jas Suri - MSFT Sorry, it is not clear to me. As I mentioned, first I tried without using Select, and yet even basic attributes like Display Name are null. And what does using beta endpoint mean? I am not very new to all this.

Comment: Before diving into the SDK, try the [graph explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer) and use the [beta](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/overview?view=graph-rest-beta) endpoint to [get user](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-get?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http). Once you see the raw attribute returned here, then you can figure out what SDK methods make sense, right now you’re fishing in the dark. Technically a B2C user doesn’t have to have any of the attributes you “selected”. Use the graph explorer to first confirm if the user has them at all

Comment: @Jas Suri - MSFT Thank you, I will be back on Wednesday, they I will check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to retrieve the user's attributes, you can try the following code, which perfectly outputs the user's attributes to the console:

```
using System;
using Microsoft.Identity.Client;
using Microsoft.Graph.Auth;
using Microsoft.Graph;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace call_api

{
    class Program
    {
        static async System.Threading.Tasks.Task Main(string[] args)



        {
            IConfidentialClientApplication app;
            app = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder.Create("{client id}")
                    .WithClientSecret("{Client Secret}")
                    .WithAuthority(new Uri("https://login.microsoftonline.com/{B2C tenant id}"))
                    .Build();



            AuthenticationResult result = null;
            string[] scopes = new string[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" };
            result = await app.AcquireTokenForClient(scopes).ExecuteAsync();
            string accesstoken = result.AccessToken;

            /*Console.WriteLine(accesstoken);*/

            ClientCredentialProvider authProvider = new ClientCredentialProvider(app);

            GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(authProvider);


            var user = await graphClient.Users["{user id}"].Request().GetAsync();

            Console.WriteLine("user properties:" + JsonConvert.SerializeObject(user));

        }
    }
}
```

[image]